# lower bound for the size of largest intersecting set of fized size

Tags: combinatorics

At the bottom of page 2 of [these notes](https://github.com/ericphanson/CombinatoricsNotes/blob/master/CombinatoricsNotes.pdf),  we should have $\binom{n-1}{r-1}\leq max|\mathcal{F}|\leq \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{r}$ right? instead of $\binom{n}{r-1}\leq max|\mathcal{F}|\leq \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{r}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is correct! But you could figer it your self.

After that they say this two values are equal (for $k=n/2$), so it should be $$\binom{n}{r-1}= \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{r}$$ which is not the case.